# Haskell - Algebraic data types that use recursion?

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types, recursive-datastructures

I've followed a guide to creating a binary search tree which uses the following datatype:

```
data BinarySearchTree a = EmptyTree | TreeNode a (BinarySearchTree a) (BinarySearchTree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

Am I correct in saying 'TreeNode' is using recursion, i.e. creates 2 elements of its own data type '(BinarySearchTree a) (BinarySearchTree a)'?

I've never seen a datatype like this, any brief explanation would be great!

Comment: It is very similar to the list type (which is recursive as well), except it recurses twice (two branches of a node in a tree) instead of once (in a list, a cell has only one tail).

Comment: Technically, `TreeNode` *takes* two `BinarySearchTree` value (and an `a` value) and *returns* a new `BinarySearchTree` value. The *type* is defined recursively.

Comment: TreeNode does not *create* anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a recursive data type.

I recommend a relevant chapter in [Learn You A Haskell For Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#recursive-data-structures) - it is very beginner-friendly. It describes your exact case, too:

> Here's what we're going to say: a tree is either an empty tree or it's
>   an element that contains some value and two trees. Sounds like a
>   perfect fit for an algebraic data type!